# std::unordered_set insert, get the position where item was inserted

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

Assume I have class MyClass

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    MyClass( std::string str ) : _str(str) {}
    void SetPosition ( int i ) { _pos = i; }
    std::string _str;
    int _pos;
};

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<shared_ptr<MyClass>>
    {
        size_t operator()( const shared_ptr<MyClass> & ptr ) const
        {
            return hash<string>()( ptr->_str ) + hash<int>()( ptr->_pos );
        }
    };
}
```

When using std::vector, I was able to do this:

```
std::string str = "blah";
auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>( str );
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> vector;
vector.push_back( ptr );
ptr->SetPosition ( std::addressof( vector.back() ) - std::addressof( vector[0] ) );
std::cout <<  ptr->_str <<  " is at " << ptr->_pos << std::endl;
```

In order to calculate where in the vector, my object pointer was placed.

However, If I want to use std::unordered_set (which I do), then:

```
std::string str = "blah";
auto ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>( str );
std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> set;
auto res = set.insert( ptr );
ptr->SetPosition ( std::addressof( res.first ) - std::addressof( set[0] ) );
std::cout <<  ptr->_str <<  " is at " << ptr->_pos << std::endl;
```

Will not work.
Neither will

```
std::addressof( set.begin() );
```

Nor will,

```
std::addressof( set.begin().first );
```

or any other way I try to use the front iterator.

1. Does this make sense? Or should I rely on set.size() and **assume** that my pointer was inserted at the end?
2. Is there any way to safely get the position where that pointer was inserted using something similar to the above code?

Comment: Position does not make much sense for an unordered set because it is unordered.

Comment: Not only is it unordered, the position of your item in the set might change after an insert. A hash might switch hashing functions and copy into a larger structure, for example.

Comment: And of course future inserts into the unordered set might go into a hash bucket before your item, pushing it farther down in position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unordered_set, like the name implies, is unordered. You can keep track of the position of your elements in a vector, because as long as you don't erase anything, they won't change places. But that's not true of unordered_set. For instance, on my implementation, here's what printing all the elements in order after every insert would yield:

```
std::unordered_set<int> s;
s.insert(0); // 0
s.insert(1); // 1 0
s.insert(2); // 2 1 0
s.insert(3); // 3 2 1 0
...
s.insert(22); // 22 0 1 2 3 ... 19 20 21
...
s.insert(48); // 48 47 46 45 ... 22 0 1 2 3 4 ... 21
```

So what I'm trying to say is order is definitely not something that makes sense for you to rely on.

With your vector, however, you can do much better in terms of setting position:

```
vector.push_back(ptr);
ptr->SetPosition(vector.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense. Out of curiosity, are insertions performed at random places?

Comment: @Alex - Random? No. They're inserted into a bucket according to a hash function, to ensure that `find` is amortized constant time. You can check yourself which bucket a key gets inserted into with `bucket(const Key&)` and you can iterate over a particular bucket with `begin(size_t)` and `end(size_t)`.